# How to find basis vector from a differential equation. How to find its transformation matrix relatively to its initial value.

Tags: linear-algebra

1. The solution to the linear differential equation  $\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}=u$ form a vector space (since combinations of solutions are still solutions). Find two independent solutions, to give a basis for that solution space.
2. With intial value $u=x$ and $\frac{du}{dt} = y$ at $t=0$, what combination of basis vectors in Problem 1 solves $\frac{d^2u}{dt^2} = u$?  This transformation from intial values to solution is linear. What is its 2 by 2 matrix (using $x =1, y = 0$ and $x = 0, y = 1$ as basis for **V**, and your basis for **W**.

Please kindly assist me in these 2 questions. For problem 1, I somehow know the basis is $e^t$ and $e^{-t}$ from an intuitive sense. I checked the answer, it was correct but I have no idea how to find the answer through a proper method. If the question is complicated, I bet I can't solve it. Hence, I hope someone can solve the above 2 questions and explains the solutions to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1) The solutions you $e^t$ and $e^{-t}$ you have found by intuition are independant because their wronskian

$$\begin{vmatrix}e^t&e^{-t}\\e^t&-e^{-t}\end{vmatrix}=2$$

is non-zero.

2) One finds without difficulty that the combination of these basis functions fullfilling conditions $u=x$ and $\frac{du}{dt} = y$ is the following function:

$$f(t)=\dfrac{x+y}{2}e^t+\dfrac{x-y}{2}e^{-t}.$$

Thus the linear transformation is

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{x+y}{2}\\\dfrac{x-y}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

Which amounts to

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{1}{2}&\dfrac{1}{2}\\\dfrac{1}{2}&-\dfrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} $$

with the matrix that is asked for.

Answer (score 0):

In general, given a differential equation of the form $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k y^{(k)}=0$$ where $a_k$ are scalars and $y^{(k)}$ denotes the $k$-th derivative we can find a solution of the form $y=e^{\lambda x}$. Plug it in the equation we will have $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k \lambda^k e^{\lambda x}=0\implies \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k\lambda^k=0$$ i.e, we have some characteristic polynomial which corresponds to the differential equation.

We want the solutions to be linearly independent, thus if some solution $\lambda_i$ have multiplicity $k_i>1$ we will take the solutions $e^{\lambda x},xe^{\lambda x},\dots,x^{k_i-1}e^{\lambda x}$. Easy to check that forms linear independent set.

---

In the case of $n=2$ we get a quadratic equation $a_1\lambda+a_2\lambda^2-a_0=0$. Solving it we have $$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{-a_1\pm\sqrt{a_1^2+4a_2a_0}}{2a_2}$$ Now, we have three cases:

1. $a_1^2+4a_2a_0>0$, hence we have two real solutions. The solution of the differential equation is $y=C_1e^{\lambda_1 x}+C_2e^{\lambda_2 x}$.
2. $a_1^2+4a_2a_0=0$, hence we have one real solution. We want the solutions be linearly independent, thus the solution will be $y=C_1e^{\lambda x}+C_2xe^{\lambda x}$.
3. $a_1^2+4a_2a_0<0$, hence we have two complex solutions, i.e $\lambda_1=\mu+\eta i,\lambda_2=\mu-\eta i$ where $\mu,\eta\in\Bbb{R}$. The solution will be $$y=C_1e^{(\mu_i+\eta_i i)x}+C_2e^{(\mu_i-\eta_i i)x}=C_1e^{\mu x}\cos(\eta x)+C_2e^{\mu x}\sin(\eta x)$$

---

Using the above you can easily find that $e^t,e^{-t}$ are linearly independent solutions of the equation $u''=u$, which is $u(t)=C_1e^t+C_2e^{-t}$. Now we use initial conditions \begin{align*}u(0)&=C_1+C_2=x \\ u'(0)&=C_1-C_2=y\end{align*} Solving we get $C_1=\dfrac{x+y}{2} \ , \ C_2=\dfrac{x-y}{2}$, hence $$u(t)=\frac{x+y}{2}e^t+\frac{x-y}{2}e^{-t}$$ And the linear transformation is $$T\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{x+y}{2}\\\dfrac{x-y}{2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{1}{2}&\dfrac{1}{2}\\\dfrac{1}{2}&-\dfrac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$$